LSP configuration for Zig in zed
I am using zed with zig plugin version 1.1 and zls. I want set up some options like in sublime text
{
    "languages": {
        "Zig": {
            "language_servers": ["zls"]
        }
    },
    "lsp": {
        "zls": {
            "settings": {
                "enable_build_on_save": true,
                "enable_autofix": true,
                "warn_style": true,
                "highlight_global_var_declarations": true
            }
        }
    }
}

but it's not working. Is there anything I should change?

According to the docs lsp settings need to be made in an initialization_options field. Also, the posted json is missing a closing brace.

I checked and brace is correct, maybe lost it when tried to clear it from another settings for posting there. Changing 'settings' to 'initialization_options' does nothing(

I would try putting the full path to zls in "language_servers": ["/opt/whereisit/bin/zls"]
